# What Do I Need To Set Directory To

Tags: php

I get this error when my script is trying to put an image in a folder. The photo should be going in techportal/images/1/image.jpg. What do I need to define my directory as to make this work right?

```
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/var/tmp/phpsYW3wW' to '../images/1/profile.jpg' in /home4/saintfiv/public_html/pianotunerpros/techportal/index.php on line 26
```

Comment: set permission so that the web server user can write to the desired folder

Comment: log in thru FTP client find desired folder and right click on it set permissions (not _0777_) `0644` to the folder

Comment: @Kyslik: If the issue is about permissions, 0644 should be enough for images (read/write for owner, just read for anyone else). In some cases you might need 0664 though (shared access).

Comment: Also, it might be worth it to read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php
@Kyslik Not so sure about the permissions thing... I think if it was a permissions issue, it would send out a 'permission denied' warning or something, no?

Comment: Be careful: 777 means that **everyone** will be able to write to that folder. You want to use something less permissive, but the correct value depends on the server setup.

Comment: I changed the permissions but still get the same error

Comment: Thank you all for comments about 0777 :). I am used to `0777` as localhost developer, ofc it should be `0644` on live server. @Joum I think it is permission related, unless server is _weirdly_ configured.

Comment: @Kyslik it isn't weirdly configured... it would be if in a 'permission' error/warning, it wasn't specified... :)

Comment: I have 644 for files and 755 for directories, is that ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error reports the script path:

```
/home4/saintfiv/public_html/pianotunerpros/techportal/index.php
```

In a simple setup, a "../images/1/profile.jpg" path does not point to the location you want.

Try using "images/1/profile.jpg" and make sure the directory is created and writable.

Also, to make certain which directory you are in try playing with the getcwd() and chdir() functions, they can help you out a lot in debugging:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

Comment: getting rid of the slash in front did it

Answer (score 0):

few day back i'm facing same problem i think this error occurs due incorrect path provide by you.you provide path like `"../images/1/profile.jpg"` is incorrect way you use like `"images/1/profile.jpg"`.`use dirname(__FILE__) give you present location of file` and you have provide path from location to where you want to upload.
like:-

```
"C:\wamp\www\familypark\administer" //location where my upload.php file exits
"C:\wamp\www\familypark\administer\assets\upload\park_images"//location from root where i want to upload my picture
so i used like this and hence it work fine
$path='assets/upload/park_logo/';
                                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo_upload']['tmp_name'],$path.$_FILES['logo_upload']['name']);
```